# One of my questions is not visible in my profile

Tags: support, questions

I have raised the question "Unable to login with my Yahoo ID" regarding the error message displayed below.

[alt text http://img163.imageshack.us/img163/3227/stack.jpg](http://img163.imageshack.us/img163/3227/stack.jpg)

The question is not visible in my profile page any longer.

[alt text http://img689.imageshack.us/img689/607/profilev.jpg](http://img689.imageshack.us/img689/607/profilev.jpg)
What happened?

Comment: What are you even pointing out? Apply freehand circles as required on points of focus.

Comment: The question what i have raised previously isn't visible. The title is more or less as same as “unable to login with my yahoo id” which isn't visible in my list of 7 questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question has been deleted. Therefore it will not show in your list if you have less then 10K reputation.

[Unable to Log in with My Yahoo ID](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29530/unable-to-log-in-with-my-yahoo-id-no-openid-endpoint-found) (Only visible to 10K+ users)

It was deleted by Jeff 7 hours ago. You will need to e-mail him directly to confirm why. I suspect it is due to you commenting that it was working again and the problem was not reproducible.

Comment: Somehow you were able to understand what the question was even bringing up.

Comment: Only because I look at the deleted and closed lists at least every 8 hours or so. I am like a bot.

Answer (score 2):

The question list in your screenshot is sorted by votes. Te new question would not be at the top of that list, try clicking on the recent tab.

Comment: Totally there are 7 questions and all the 7 are visible

Comment: Upvote! OMG! how is this possible?

Comment: This was up-voted since it could be correct based on your screenshot. However further investigation showed that the question was deleted, however this is one way to see all your latest questions.

Comment: Yea for the magic waffle ponies of meta upvoting!